# CH and embeddings of $\aleph_2$ into Pow($\omega$)

Tags: set-theory

CH is false iff $\aleph_2$ is embeddable in Pow($\omega$).
But in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344346210) paper they write on the very first line the opposite: CH is apparently *true* if
$\aleph_2$ is emebeddable in Pow($\omega$).
So why , what's wrong ?

Comment: That's a remark with a reference to another paper. Maybe look at that paper and see what it says. Presumably there are more details there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The term "true" is subject to understanding that some people expect mathematics to have an objective and concrete truth value, independent of our thoughts. They may argue that certain axioms are more plausible than others, and are therefore more likely to be true. This, in time, and with some mathematical work, can lead certain people to make claims about mathematical "truth".
2. The text says exactly the opposite of what you claim that it says. It says that if $\aleph_2$ could be embedded into $2^{\aleph_0}$, that should have been apparent. It's not, apparent to the author, and therefore they claim that it is false, and in fact much more is true.
3. The text is building upon previous work of the author where they already claim that the Continuum Hypothesis is true, and they now chose to extend this claim to say that $V=L$ is true.

The problem with "apparent", of course, that it is very much a cultural thing, based on the exact coordinates of your existence in the spacetime continuum. Different things are apparent to different people in different times and different places. So I'd take any claim about "truth" with a grain of salt. Including my claims that there isn't any.

Comment: "Including my claims that there isn't any". Except for large cardinals. And choice.

Comment: :-) ${} {} {} $